# Why doesn't my SKSprite react to collisions when it's attached to a SKPhysicsJointPin?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

In the image below you can see 3 sprites, all with SKPhysicsBodies attached to them.  The red circle is a swivel point, and the blue rectangle is a "paddle" which is attached to the swivel with a SKPhysicsJointPin.  The paddle works just as it should.  Gravity makes it swing back and forth, and if I have other Fields in the area they will cause the paddle to wiggle as well.

However, the one thing that doesn't work are collisions.  If the green ball hits the paddle, the green ball bounces off of it, but the paddle does absolutely nothing.  The ball as a mass = 1.0, and I set the paddle to mass = 0.1, so the ball should have a very noticeable effect when it hits the paddle.

What am I missing?

[image: red = hinge, blue = paddle, green = ball]

Comment: what do you have as the collision? Are you setting it as bluePaddleNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = greenBall;? or
bluePaddleNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = greenBall;? I've noticed that when doing the contactBitMask, it only notices contact. When i used collisionBitMask, it reacts itself within the app. Don't forget to do the same with greenBallNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = bluePaddle; or greenBallNode.physicsBody.contactBitMask = bluePaddle; as well

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're right.  This is what happens when I work 14 hours a day.  I had the collision mask on the ball, so the ball would hit the paddle, but I didn't have the mask on the paddle, so the paddle didn't react to the ball.  All fixed now :)